# Will Cognito User Pools support internationalization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, internationalization, amazon-cognito

We are very excited about the new Cognito User Pools. But it looks like that there is no way to support multiple languages in messages.

For example a User from Germany should get a verification message in German while a user from New Zealand should get it in English.

Without internationalization nobody could use Cognito User Pools outside of English speaking countries.

Will this be a feature in the final release on Cognito User Pools?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Lambda Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) functionality with Cognito User pools to customize the messages that are sent to your users.

The Custom Message Lambda Trigger sends you an event source which can help you identify a particular user pool or user and then return the service a message template which will be used when sending SMS or Email message. It should conform to the contract of including {####} as code parameter.

In you specific case, to identify users from a particular country you can create a [Custom Attribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-settings.html) in your user pool for source country. In each SignUp call you can set that value and the service will send that value to your lambda function.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try. Thanks.